# Where are the Chrome Dimension pickups in Chrome.Angrybirds?

Tags: angry-birds

The browser-based verison of Angry Birds seems to have an extra suite of levels you can unlock if you find and hit a google chrome logo within a level with a bird.

There appear to be 7 levels in total (so far), and while I've unlocked #3 and #6, I'd like to unlock the others as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Angry Birds Nest has a guide](http://www.angrybirdsnest.com/2011/05/how-to-unlock-all-the-angry-birds-chrome-dimension-levels/), as usual.  Summarized below:

> **Chrome Dimension Level 1 unlocked in Poached Eggs Level 1-16**
>  To unlock this level zoom out and shoot a yellow bird up to the ledge in the sky.
>
>
>  **Chrome Dimension Level 2 unlocked in Poached Eggs Level 1-18**
>  The logo is on top of the cliff to the far right. Zoom out and nail it with a yellow bird.
>
>  **Chrome Dimension Level 3 unlocked in Poached Eggs Level 1-20**
>  If you zoom out you’ll see the Chrome logo swaying in the breeze above you. Time it right and victory is yours!
>
>  **Chrome Dimension Level 4 unlocked in Poached Eggs Level 2-4**
>  Zoom out and you’ll see the Chrome logo way over yonder behind them bolders.
>
>  **Chrome Dimension Level 5 unlocked in Poached Eggs Level 2-20**
>  This one is a bit tricky! If you zoom out you’ll see the logo on the far right behind a tall wall. The best way to get this one is with the white bird. Launch it at the very last pig and drop the egg bomb right on top if him. The explosion should be enough to snag it!
>
>  **Chrome Dimension Level 6 unlocked in Poached Eggs Level 3-7**
>  Dude! It’s right there in front of the slingshot. Bounce red bird off the structure, but don’t pull the slingshot back all the way or you’ll overshoot it.
>
>  **Chrome Dimension Level 7 unlocked in Poached Eggs Level 3-14**
>  Zoom out and you’ll see the logo nestled in the nook behind the slingshoot. Shoot a red bird every so gingerly backwards to hit it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are into unlocking all levels, follow [this link](http://wesbos.com/all-levels-html5-angry-birds/).
Beware, though, it's a cheat.