# What does getting the Chrome icon in Angry Birds Chrome Edition do?

Tags: angry-birds, google-chrome

I played the Chrome version of Angry Birds.  In level 3-7, there is a Chrome icon that you can get.  I got it and it became big and it disappeared.

I didn't beat the level on the first try, but the chrome icon is not there anymore when I attempt to finish this level.

Did I get a bonus or something else? Did I miss something by failing the level after hitting the icon?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This unlocks the sixth "Chrome Dimension Level".  So yeah, you got a bonus level :).  [The Chrome Dimension appears as an episode](http://angrybirds.wikia.com/wiki/Chrome_Dimension) (set of levels) in the main menu area of the game.

Check out [another of my answers](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/22080/where-are-the-chrome-dimension-pickups-in-chrome-angrybirds/22103#22103) if you want to see the locations of the other Chrome Dimension pickups and how to get them.

Answer (score 1):

I had that happen on 4 of them. Im guessing since I now have 3 stars on all the levels and only got 3 of the chrome dimensions unlocked but all the chrome icons are gone because I failed the level when I got those icons and I haven't found another way to get them... yup we've missed out. I now have to wait for new friends to join before I get any new levels to play.